# checkbox change not detected when checkbox is checked remotely

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

I have two checkboxes. When the first is checked, I force the second to be checked too. When the second is checked, I want to toggle a message. But the change event is not detected on the second when first one is checked:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#first").change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")){
   $("#second").prop('checked', true).attr("disabled","disabled");
  } else {
   $("#second").prop('checked', false).removeAttr("disabled");
  }
 });
 
 
 $("#second").change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")){
   $("#alert").show();
  } else {
   $("#alert").hide();
  }
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="checkbox">first &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input id="second" type="checkbox">second
<br><br>
<div id="alert" style="display:none">This is an alert</div>
```

Comment: Side note, instead of doing `$(this).is(":checked")` just do `this.checked`.  You already have the element and checked is a readily available property off of it.  No reason to create a jQuery object and use a method to get a property that is already available to you.

Comment: So you want to add an event on a disabled element?

Comment: The trigger works on disabled elements in accepted answer. @MasterYoda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical changes to a dom element do not generate events.  If you want an event run `trigger('change')` on it after the fact to generate an event.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't work as expected because when you dynamcally set something, its event is not dispatched like a mouseclick will do.

So, you need to manually dispatch the event.

In jQuery, you can use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#second").prop('checked', true).attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else {
            $("#second").prop('checked', false).removeAttr("disabled");
        }

        // ADDED THIS LINE
        $('#second').trigger('change');
    });
 
 
    $("#second").change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#alert").show();
        } else {
            $("#alert").hide();
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="checkbox">first &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input id="second" type="checkbox">second
<br><br>
<div id="alert" style="display:none">This is an alert</div>
```